# How to echo elements from Multimdimensional array with different no. of sub-arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

This is my multidimensional array.
http://pastebin.com/iHtNYCQg

First array contains 3 sub-arrays.
Second array contains 2 sub-arrays.
Third array contains 4 sub-arrays.

How can i loop over these sub-arrays and display them ?

Comment: Include a minimal part of your code in the question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($start_array as $sub_array) {
    foreach ($sub_array as $innermost_array) {
       echo print_r($innermost_array, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks the problem is solved,
Now one more query ,i have added a date element in my array now i want to sort this array in descending order.How can i do this?

Comment: @BrainyPrb: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: Multidimensional array is to be sorted but it is sorting only sub-arrays within it.

Comment: @BrainyPrb: google is your firend -> http://php.net/manual/it/function.array-multisort.php :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// Outer loop
foreach($array as $sub) {
     // Output if no sub array
     if(!is_array($sub)) {
         var_dump($sub);
     }
     // Inner loop if sub array
     else {
         foreach($sub as $item) {
             var_dump($item);
         }
     }
}
```